# Will the Core Set cards be avaliable for the Wild format?

Tags: hearthstone

I'm a wild hearthstone player and was just wondering if I could play the new Core Set cards in the Wild format when the new set goes live?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the core set in Wild. Confirmed in Blizzard's announcement blog.

https://playhearthstone.com/en-gb/news/23620129

> Is the Core Set only playable in Standard?
>
> No. The Core set can be used in Wild as well.